# Show a specific dropdown box after select a option from another dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dropdown box list and have some forms .i want to show specific form against dropdown box value. suppose dropdown box contains two list such as: (i)Man (ii)Animal. when Man option is selected then it enters into a form which contains two option male and female.On the other hand(for animal) it enters into a form which contains three option lions,tigers,cow. 
how to write this statement in a html and javascripts code ???

Comment: Provide us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i could not write jquery code for this . @Krusader. can i provide html portion without script portion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="formSelector">
        <option value="0">select form type</option>
        <option value="humanForm">human</option>
        <option value="animalForm">animal</option>
    </select>
    <div id="humanForm" style="display:none;">
        <input type="radio" name="humanSelector" />Man
        <input type="radio" name="humanSelector" />Woman
    </div>
    <div id="animalForm" style="display:none;">

        <input type="radio" name="animalSelector" />cat
        <input type="radio" name="animalSelector" />dog
        <input type="radio" name="animalSelector" />lion
    </div>
    <script>
        var formSelector = document.getElementById("formSelector");
        var humanForm = document.getElementById("humanForm");
        var animalForm = document.getElementById("animalForm");

        formSelector.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
            humanForm.style.display = "none";
            animalForm.style.display = "none";

            switch (formSelector.value) {
                case "humanForm":
                    humanForm.style.display = "block";

                    break;
                case "animalForm":
                    animalForm.style.display = "block";
                    break;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, you can do  this with a few lines of jquery, you just need to bind a select's onchange event to hide each form type, then show the right form based on the select's new value.

Here is an example of this working:

https://codepen.io/jcapinc/pen/YrJobM

## JQuery/Javascript

```
$(function(){
  var hidestuff = function(){
    $(".man-form,.animal-form").hide();
  }

  $("select[name='formtype']").change(function(){
    hidestuff();

    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == "man"){
      $(".man-form").show();
    }
    if(value == "animal"){
      $(".animal-form").show();
    }
  });
  hidestuff();
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <form>
      <h1>Creature Form</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formtype">Choose Creature Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="formtype">
          <option value="">- Choose - </option>
          <option value="man">Man</option>
          <option value="animal">Animal</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="man-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="manstuff">Man Stuff</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="animal-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="animalstuff">Animal Stuff</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I assumed this was two selects, but I see you want to show/hide a form, in which case, I'd recommend [Jeffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771158).*

There needs to be some relation between the first select and the second select.  One way would be to add an attribute called `data-relation` which connects both selects.  On any `change`, the select will be updated.  You will need to add things like initial display and displaying only non-hidden options, but I'll leave that for you.

```js
var cat = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var opt = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1];

cat.addEventListener('change', function(s) {
  for (var i = 0; i < opt.options.length; i++)
    opt.options[i].hidden = opt.options[i].dataset.relation !== s.target.value;
});
```

```html
<select>
<option>man</option>
<option>animal</option>
</select>

<select>
<option data-relation=man>male</option>
<option data-relation=man>female</option>
<option data-relation=animal>lions</option>
<option data-relation=animal>tigers</option>
<option data-relation=animal>cow</option>
</select>
```